# How to append input values to a list in Ionic App (VueJS)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

Solved:

change @input="input.barcode.push($event.target.value)" to
@input="input.barcode[index]=($event.target.value)"

I have an app that has a series of text input fields. When the submit button is clicked I want to append all the input values to two lists 'barcode' and 'location'. It works when there is only one character for each entry, however when there is more than one character I get something like this:

Barcode Input1 = 'test'

barcode = ['t', 'te', 'tes', 'test']

```
<template>
  <ion-grid>
    <form @submit="onSubmit">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Barcode:</ion-label>
            <ion-input
              :value="input.barcode"
              @input="input.barcode.push($event.target.value)"
              name="barcode1">
            </ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Location:</ion-label>
            <ion-input
              :value="input.location"
              @input="input.location.push($event.target.value)"
              name="location1">
            </ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button type="Submit" expand="block" fill="outline">Submit</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </form>
  </ion-grid>
</template>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "inventoryEntry",
    data() {
      return {
        input: {
          barcode: [],
          location: []
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.input.barcode.length == this.input.location.length) {
          this.$emit("get-codes", this.input);
          this.input = { barcode: [], location: [] };
        } else {
          this.showAlert();
        }
      },
      showAlert() {
        return this.$ionic.alertController
          .create({
            message: "Inconsistent number of entries",
            buttons: ["OK"]
          })
          .then(a => a.present());
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, your problem is caused by this `@input="input.location.push($event.target.value)"`. It looks like that `@input` is acting like a `onchange` for ionic framework. If that's the case, this is why everytime your input changes it push the content of your input letter by letter.

I would recommend to try using a `v-model` to track on the content of the input and on submit push the value into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes here:
@input="input.barcode.push($event.target.value)"
Every time you press a key push value to input.barcode, so you need to use v-model (want to add finally value to your array position [0]

Here you have codesandbox working => https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-ionic-side-menus-9hp74

You cant use v-model on ion-input as tell here, but can use ionInput (@input):
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15532

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `ion-input-vue`

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked" color="primary">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input-vue
      autocomple="off"
      v-model="inputData.email"
      name="username"
      type="email"
      spellcheck="false"
      autocapitalize="off"
    ></ion-input-vue>
  </ion-item>
```